# IIS6 error"The handle is invalid" when closing the IIS Manager mmc

Tags: iis-6, iis

We have a couple of servers that for some reason, show an error dialog when closing out of the IIS Manager.  The error gives absolutely no information, and searches on Google and Bing have returned nothing.

The error is shown here:

[image: Error The handle is invalid]

There's nothing in the event log to correspond with the error, and I cannot find any other informaiton about the error to assist in troubleshooting.

The servers are Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition Service Pack 2, with IIS 6 installed.

Has anybody seen this, and does anyone have a way to correct this issue?
I realize I may not have posted enough information to answer teh question, but this is really all I have.  If you have other suggestions as to where to look for more details, I'm open to suggestions.

**Added**

We've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling IIS to no avail.

Comment: I have seen this before on servers, but I have never found a solution to it; on the other hand it was never anything more than annoying to me (it didn't affect the functionality of the server).

Comment: It was only an annoyance to me as well, up until today.  I got it after attempting to set IP restrictions on a web app, and now NOTHING can access it, and any attempt to save the restrictions results in the error. - but thanks for commenting.

Comment: What if you open via the MMC and add the snap-in? Does that still get the same error as InetMgr?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Uninstalling and reinstalling IIS doesn't work either.

Comment: Is it possible any of your .Net frameworks have become corrupt?

Comment: @David George - I suppose it's possible, but we have never had errors in any of the ASP.NET web apps on the server.  This error has been coming up for a few years, and as I've said until today it's only been a minor annoyance.  Other than this error, these servers give us no issues at all.

Comment: Well with no other errors that would be unlikely. All my searching brings up different crypto resources, nothing rock solid pointing to your issue; just a lot of IIS5 garbage. Have you read through: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;278381 And http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812614

Comment: I hadn't until you posted them, but nothing in those applies. The permissions are set properly.  (I checked, which is why it took so long to reply.)

Comment: I thought I had it - I restored the IIS Metabase to the original install date, and the errors went away - until I got the SSL Cert installed.  Then I started getting errors again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this occur on one of our servers.  When I was logged on as user X I got the error "The Handle is invalid".  I logged off the machine and back on as a different user and did NOT get the error in the IIS Manager.  Both users were domain and local administrators but there must have been something about one of the accounts I was using to update IIS that it didn't like.  I honestly have no idea what it is but maybe this can help in your situation.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not sure that this will help either, but it's something I hadn't considered and is good to know.